# getting an error when I am trying to add an asset through transaction in hyperledger composer

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-composer

**sample.cto file**

```
  namespace org.example.basic

    asset Supplier identified by suppliername
    {
      o String suppliername
    }
    asset product identified by productname{
    o String productname
    -->Supplier supplier
    o Integer amount
    }



    transaction SampleTransaction {
      -->product productasset
      o String productname
      o String supplier
      o Integer amount
    }
```

**logic.js file**

/**
 * Sample transaction processor function.
 * @param {org.example.basic.SampleTransaction} tx The sample transaction instance.
 * @transaction
 */

```
async function createPost(tx) {

      var factory = getFactory();
      return getAssetRegistry("org.example.basic.product")
      .then(function(postAssetRegistry) {
       var productname=tx.productname
       newPost = factory.newResource("org.example.basic", "product", productname);
       newPost.productname = tx.productname;
       newPost.supplier = tx.supplier;
       newPost.amount=tx.amount;

       return postAssetRegistry.add(newPost);
  })





}
```

[click here to view error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yX9Ke.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your transaction definition in the model file you are specifying a string, but in this line of the script `newPost.supplier = tx.supplier;` the newPost.supplier property is being enforced by Composer to be a relationship so would have a value something like `org.example.basic.Supplier#qqa`